# Chamar um arraylist de outro metodo, pra imprimir no metodo diferente

Tags: php

quero pegar as informações do arraylist dentro de uma determinado metodo, pra imprimir em outro metodo.

Não esta imprimindo nada, minha logica esta certa ?
class Agenda
    //Class Agenda
    var $bancoDeDados = array();

```
public function adicionar($add){
        $bancoDeDados[] = $add;

}

public function view(){
    foreach ($this->bancoDeDados as $key) {
        echo "voce escreveu:".$key;
    }
}
```

}

```html
class pessoaFisica extends Agenda
{
 function __construct(){

 }
  }
  
  
  
  
  
$pf = new PessoaFisica();

$pf->adicionar("ola mundo");
$pf->View();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na função `adicionar` você não adiciona um item no array, apenas o sobreescreve com um array de um item só (o novo, que deveria ser adicionado), além disso, a função tem um loop que não faz nada

Imagino que você quer algo assim:

```
class Teste {
    public $bancoDeDados = array();

    public function adicionar($add){
        $this->bancoDeDados[] = $add;
    }

    public function view(){
        foreach ($this->bancoDeDados as $key) {
            echo "\nvoce escreveu: ".$key;
        }
    }
}

$teste = new Teste();

$teste->adicionar("foo");
$teste->adicionar("bar");
$teste->view();
```

Retorna:

```
voce escreveu: foo
voce escreveu: bar
```

Mas se a função só faz isso não precisa dela, é bem mais simples usar o método `$variavel[] = 'valor'`;

Comment: nao deu. , nao funcionou.

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: vou editar o meu codigo, coloccar completo com a herança

Comment: editado, segue o codigo.

Comment: Sua edição não ajudou muito, esse é o código completo? Porque não está funcionando? Algum erro?

Comment: nao percebi o erro, peço desculpas, obrigado pela dicas.

Answer (score 0):

**O erro ocorre aqui:**
Na classe Agenda, você está passando o parâmetro `$add` para uma variável do tipo array chamada `$bancoDeDados` e não para uma propriedade chamada `bancoDeDados`.

Seu código funciona simplesmente atribuindo a variável $add a uma propriedade chamada `bancoDeDados` na classe Agenda. Assim:

`$this->bancoDeDados = $add;`

Seu código na classe agenda então fica:

```
class Agenda {

    public function adicionar($add) {

        $this->bancoDeDados = $add;
    }

    public function view() {

        foreach ($this->bancoDeDados as $key) {
            echo "voce escreveu:" . $key;
        }
    }

}
```

É interessante que você defina a propriedade antes de utilizá-la, logo:

```
class Agenda {

    public $bancoDeDados;

    public function adicionar($add) {

        $this->bancoDeDados = $add;
    }

    public function view() {

        foreach ($this->bancoDeDados as $key) {
            echo "voce escreveu:" . $key;
        }
    }

}
```

Se você quiser que a propriedade seja um array, defina: `public $bancoDeDados = array();`, logo:

```
class Agenda {

    public $bancoDeDados = array();

    public function adicionar($add) {

        $this->bancoDeDados = $add;
    }

    public function view() {

        foreach ($this->bancoDeDados as $key) {
            echo "voce escreveu:" . $key;
        }
    }

}
```

Você define a propriedade `bancoDeDados` como um array mas está passando uma string. Já que é um array, você também pode passar como parâmetro um array:

```
<?php

class Agenda {

    public $bancoDeDados = array();

    public function adicionar($add) {
        $this->bancoDeDados = $add;
    }

    public function view() {

        echo "Você escreveu:";
        foreach ($this->bancoDeDados as $index => $dados) {
            echo "<Br>" . $index . $dados;
        }
    }

}

class PessoaFisica extends Agenda {
    function __construct() {
    }
}

$pf = new PessoaFisica();

$pf->adicionar(array('Id: ' => 7, 'Nome: ' => "Luiz"));

$pf->View();
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas.